# When use MySQL select JSON which sub key is a number

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

```
select props->>"$.redirect" from jsonDoc
```

The result is:

[image: the result]

How to select the 403 just like `select props->>"$.redirect.403" from jsonDoc`

thanks

Comment: Try: `SELECT \`props\` ->> '$.redirect."403"' FROM \`jsonDoc\`;`.

Comment: thank you very much , it works ~ thanks thanks thanks